# Where to find rat genome for STAR alignment?

Tags: sequence-alignment, genome

I'm trying to find the rat genome to carry out STAR alignment for several FASTQ files.  Where would I find these files?

Answer (score 2):

For example from Ensembl: https://www.ensembl.org/Rattus_norvegicus/Info/Index

Can find other links via a search engine of choice.